# Pass several arguments or a dictionary to a deferred function (deferred.defer / pickle)?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, pickle

Knowing that the deferred task will be called thousands of times a day, what is better between the two following methods (in terms of bandwidth and cpu using Google App Engine)?

As I guess arguments will be pickled differently and the POST request size will be affected, as well as the defer call duration.

**1st method:**

```
from google.appengine.ext import deferred

def do_something_later(string1, string2, string3, string4):
    template_values = {
        'stuff': string1,
        'specs': string2,
        'misc1': string3,
        'misc2': string4,
    }
    # do something with template_values

deferred.defer(do_something_later, string1, string2, string3, string4)
```

**2nd method:**

```
from google.appengine.ext import deferred

def do_something_later(template_values):
    # do something with template_values

template_values = {
    'stuff': string1,
    'specs': string2,
    'misc1': string3,
    'misc2': string4,
}
deferred.defer(do_something_later, template_values)
```

Answer (score 2):

I can't imagine any circumstances in which this will make a difference. The difference in size between the first and second options is a few bytes only. Even run thousands of times a day, you're only talking about a few Kb over that period. It's really not worth bothering about. You should use whichever one makes more sense for your code.

Comment: Any info on how things differ under the hood?